# Alternative to TopMost with no focus on the taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, taskbar, topmost

i got a problem with a wpf application. I got a checkbox to set the window always on top, but when i activate the checkbox and set TopMost = true not only my window gets in front, also the taskbar.
My problem is, my application should stay in front of another fullscreen application. This means, only the window should be in focus, not the taskbar. 
I found a solution with hiding the taskbar completely as soon i active TopMost... but this is not a satisfying solution, because the taskbar is also hidden, when I use my tool without the fullscreen application.

Summary:
- setting the application window always on top with my checkbox
- with my fullscreen application running, there should be no focus on the taskbar
- when running without the fullscreen application, the taskbar should be shown without focus.

I hope somebody can help me and thanks for your attention.

best regards,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works, but you can try this: disable the Taskbar-Icon for your TopMost-App.

Another workaround would be to let the taskbar always slide out of view (its a taskbar setting)